# how to filter component in PreFilterMessage

Tags: c#, user-controls, desktop, mouseclick-event

How to reject *all controls that come from outside the user control* **except buttons from within this user control** when *left mouse clicked* in *PreFilterMessage*.

```
public partial class Pagination : UserControl, IMessageFilter
{
    public const int WM_LBUTTONDOWN = 0x0201;
    public const int WM_LBUTTONUP = 0x0202;

    public Pagination()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Application.AddMessageFilter(this);
        Disposed += PaginationFilter_Disposed;
    }

    private void PaginationFilter_Disposed(object? sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Application.RemoveMessageFilter(this);
    }

    public bool PreFilterMessage(ref Message m)
    {
        // How to reject all controls that come from outside the user control except buttons from within this user control when left mouse clicked.   
         
        Point client = PointToClient(MousePosition);
        switch (m.Msg)
        {
            case WM_LBUTTONDOWN:
                if (ClientRectangle.Contains(client))
                {
                    if (ctrl is Button)
                    {
                        //Debug.Print("WM_LBUTTONDOWN " + ctrl.Name);
                    }
                    return true;
                }
                break;

            case WM_LBUTTONUP:
                if (ClientRectangle.Contains(client))
                {
                    //Debug.Print("WM_LBUTTONUP " + ctrl.Name);
                    return true;
                }
                break;

        }
        return false;
    }

}
```

I want reject *all controls that come from outside the user control* **except buttons from within this user control** when *left mouse clicked* in *PreFilterMessage*

Comment: Unclear at all.. What is the relation between the _outside_ controls and the mouse events of the UserControl's buttons? Reject them how? The buttons in the UserControl receive the mouse inputs and their `Click` events fire. Perhaps you don't need to implement the `IMessageFilter` interface at all.

Comment: **Side Note:** You must override the `OnHandleCreated` method to `Application.AddMessageFilter(this);` and override the `OnHandleDestroyed` method to `Application.RemoveMessageFilter(this);`.

Comment: @dr.null The PreFilterMessage will accept mouse down from all controls in the application, not only from the user control where the PreFilterMessage is used. If we don't do a filter, it will affect other controls which will be an error.

Comment: @dr.null I combined 2 user controls, namely combobox and pagination, and to detect click events on button pagination, I have to use IMessageFilter.

Comment: Can't just handle the buttons' click events? One handler for all and the `sender` tells you which button was clicked? Anyway, maybe you have a good reason to do so. The `m` has `HWnd` property. You can create a control from it through the `Control.FromHandle` method, then you can compare the parents. If the control is Button and its`parent is your UserControl then it belongs to it.

Comment: Something like: `if (m.Msg == WM_LBUTTONDOWN && m.HWnd != IntPtr.Zero && FromHandle(m.HWnd) is Button btn && btn.Parent == this) { ... }`.

Comment: @dr.null, thanks for point out. I resolved my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An error in the filter in **PreFilterMessage** caused all the controls I created to mess up when clicked. Thank you to dr.null for giving me a point out.

Filters on **WM_LBUTTONDOWN** and **WM_LBUTTONUP** must be the same, that's the key so bugs don't occur.

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
private static extern IntPtr WindowFromPoint(Point pnt);

private bool hitButton(Control control, Point point)
{
    if (control.Bounds.Contains(point))
    {
        switch (control.Name)
        {
            // do button jobs
        }
    }
    return false;
}

private Control? _controlSelected;
private Point _client;

public bool PreFilterMessage(ref Message m)
{

    IntPtr hWnd = WindowFromPoint(MousePosition);
    if (hWnd != IntPtr.Zero)
    {
        _controlSelected = Control.FromHandle(hWnd);
        if (_controlSelected == null)
        {
            return false; // searching next control
        }
    }
    _client = PointToClient(MousePosition);

    switch (m.Msg)
    {
        case WM_LBUTTONDOWN:
            if (ClientRectangle.Contains(_client))
            {
                if (_controlSelected != null)
                {
                    if (_controlSelected.Name == nameof(FirstPaginationButton) || _controlSelected.Name == nameof(PrevPaginationButton) || _controlSelected.Name == nameof(NextPaginationButton) || _controlSelected.Name == nameof(LastPaginationButton))
                    {
                        return hitButton(_controlSelected, _client); // the control is founded
                    }
                }
            }
            break;

        case WM_LBUTTONUP:
            if (ClientRectangle.Contains(_client))
            {
                if (_controlSelected != null)
                {
                    if (_controlSelected.Name == nameof(FirstPaginationButton) || _controlSelected.Name == nameof(PrevPaginationButton) || _controlSelected.Name == nameof(NextPaginationButton) || _controlSelected.Name == nameof(LastPaginationButton))
                    {
                        return true; // the control is founded
                    }
                }
            }
            break;

    }
    return false;
}
```